# The return value of "collect" must be used : error sonar java

Tags: java

I want to achieve something like this:

```
List<Event> list = query.getResultList();
    if (!query.getResultList().isEmpty()) {

        list.stream().map(event -> {
            .....
            
            return event;
            
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

but i have error sonar: the return value of collect must be used

Help please!

Comment: The point of the `collect()` method of a Stream is to transform this stream into a `List`. Also, Sonar just send warning, this should compile and run. What's the matter with Sonar sending you this error ?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback
it is a bug in the sonar analysis it must be corrected

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, it's more of a rule defined in Sonar. Though it's right, if you don't need the newly mapped list, don't use a collector. But you might be using `map` incorrectly; maybe you're looking for `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns a List. You never use it.

```
   List<YourObject> yourNewList = eventList.stream().map(event -> {
        .....
        
        return event;
        
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```